# create a loop in python to loop over files, variables, and matrix

Tags: python, loops

Does anyone can help me with creating a loop in python? I need to create a loop to loop in the same time over files, variable, and matrix. To explain better, these are the steps of my code:

1. read files using h5py library:

```
    file_00 = h5py.File('file0','r')

    file_01 = h5py.File('file1','r')
```

```
file_1000 = h5py.File('file1000','r')
```

2. Extract variables from file:

```
    alpha_00 = numpy.array(file_00['alpha'])[:,:,:,:]

    alpha_01 = numpy.array(file_01['alpha'])[:,:,:,:]
```

```
alpha_1000= numpy.array(file_1000['alpha'])[:,:,:,:]
```

3. Construct new matrix:

```
    new_alpha_1 = np.zeros([100,200,100])


    for index in range (100):
        m = 
        n = 
        p = 
        new_alpha_1[m:m+10,n:n+10,p:p+10]=alpha_1[index,:,:,:]
```

My goal is to create a loop from 0 to 1000, to read all files, extract alpha variable for all files and construct new_alpha matrix for all files.
What I tried is first looping over files by creating a list:

```
for counter in range (0,1000):
File=h5py.File('file_{0:0=4d}'.format(counter),'r')
```

This lines works and are able to read all files.
How can I create a loop to extract alpha variables for all files and construct the matrix new_alpha for all files ?

Comment: What was preventing you from writing 2 more loops like you wrote the first one?

Comment: You can put for a loop inside another for loop, the same way you do it in any other place of the code. Is called _nested loop_, if you want to search for examples.

Comment: What are you trying to combine here?  You have 1,000 files.  How large are they?  Are you trying to make each file a plane in one large array?  Or are you just trying to create 1,000 new files, where each has the "alpha" from the original files?

Comment: The goal is to loop over different files and save the output (alpha) of each files.

Comment: Looping is the easy part, just put a loop after the other, each one indented as for the previous one. It's very basic, so there are many tutorials with examples. The problem is how are you planning to save the output, in particular how are you going to assign a name to whatever is holding the data? "new_alpha_1" could be the name of a new file, a key in a dictionary... It's usually not a good idea to create names of variables implicitly.